# Should you create a var inside a for-in loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, scoping

```
for(var key in object){
  //process object[key]
}
```

or just

```
for(key in object) {
  //process object[key]
}
```

Is there a difference?

Comment: key in second case can be deleted using delete keyword

Comment: see the last two lines of this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FWorking_with_Objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there's a difference. Whether you use var or not `key` will still be a variable, and its 'life' will not actually end after `for` is done, its scope will span till the end of the function.
But if you do not use `var` - the `key` will be global.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a difference. If you haven’t declared `key`, `var key` will declare `key`. If you have, it’s a redeclaration and not really a great thing to do, but it doesn’t matter that much.

If you haven’t declared it, not declaring it and using it, like in your second sample, is bad. It will leak globally, [break in strict mode](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/CJXEL/), and be slow.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a recommendation, always go for the **var** version, it's both safer (as its scope is the smallest possible) and faster (as the interpreter won't have to search if the variable already exists in the whole global scope). Plus it's [recommanded by Google](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=var#var).